# When to worry about PHP/MySQL settings during server migration?

Tags: web-server, website

a client of mine is upgrading their server. With the upgrade comes an OS update. From Red Hat 6 to Red Hat 7. I am by no way a server expert, so just wanted to know if there will be any issues when migrating a vast amount of websites over to new server? Will be testing the websites before they go live, but do I need to worry about PHP/MySQL versions on new server?

Client is also using cloudflare. When do I need to worry about cloudflare during this whole process?

Answer (score 2):

You can predict some issues by reading the [release notes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.0_Release_Notes/index.html) for Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7, where for a Web Developer [chapter 17](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.0_Release_Notes/chap-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7.0_Release_Notes-Web_Servers_and_Services.html) might be the most relevant.

It would be important to know if the server is configured to use the [Software collections](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.0_Release_Notes/chap-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7.0_Release_Notes-Red_Hat_Software_Collections.html), with their shorter release life cycles.

Otherwise just deploy the sites, test if everything still works, check the server logs for warnings and actual errors.

Then once you've successfully completed your tests update Cloudflare to use the new server as the back-end for the domain(s).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a test server then that would be the ideal place to do this before deploying it. It is possible that some php modules or a new mysql feature might break things. Do you have a list of php modules that are currently used? Check what has changed in the Red Hat 7 version. Check the list of any reported or known issues. Check the libraries that are used by PHP/mySQL. Sometime these libraries are in /lib and sometime in /lib64 and uses symlink. I have seen issues with broken symlinks after upgrades.

Basically, do this in a test server to make your life easier.  If that is not possible have a core set of tests ready to run to figure out what is broken or not.

Comment: We will be keeping the old server and using the new server to test before deploying. So our new server IS our test server until we're ready to launch. I am not very familiar with servers, can you explain how would I do a side by side comparison of these modules? old vs new? Not sure if it helps, but we're using Plesk to manage things as well.